# warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’

Tags: c

i have written the below code in C language.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Long Double range: %lf, %lf\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);
}
```

when I compile it (with gcc (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008), it shows the below warning!!!

```
warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘long double’
```

how can i resolve this warning? i have used also `%le` and `%lg`, but warning resists!

Comment: `%Lf`, an upper L.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print a long double value, you must use the placeholder `%Lf`.